# Reset password in PBKDF2

Tags: security, passwords, pbkdf2

I store some data which is encrypted, and the key is generated based on the user's password (after hashing and salting) using PBKDF2.

I can implement password change requests simply by decrypting the data with the old password, then reencrypting the data with the new password.

However, how do I go about implementing password reset, when the user forgets their password? Should I be storing things differently to support this use case? If so, how?

Comment: Uhhhhmmmmm. Why are you encrypting passwords instead of hashing them?

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: I'm not encrypting passwords, in fact I'm hashing+salting them. But I use that as the input to PBKDF2, and from there I encrypt some of their data.

Answer (score 1):

> I can implement password change requests simply by decrypting the data
>   with the old password, then reencrypting the data with the new
>   password.
>
> However, how do I go about implementing password reset, when the user
>   forgets their password? Should I be storing things differently to
>   support this use case? If so, how?

Typically you use a Content Encryption Key or CEK. The CEK is a random key, and you use it to key you block cipher and MAC that protects the file. Each file gets its own CEK and other crypto parameters, like and IV or nonce.

Then you use a Key Encryption Key or KEK. In you case, the KEK would be the output of you PBKDF. The KEK encrypts the CEK.

For recovery, you create a recovery key. Then you encrypt the CEK again under the recovery key, and move the encrypted CEK somewhere safe.

When it comes time to change passwords, you just re-encrypt the CEK under the new PBKDF derivation. No need to mess with the recovery key since its safe somewhere else. (Or as safe as it can be with governments issuing [NSLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_security_letter) with no oversight).